# Spring batch job parameters

Tags: configuration, spring-batch

My Spring batch configuration is below:

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfiguration1 {

  @Autowired
  protected JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  @Autowired
  protected StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Bean     
  public Job job1() throws Exception {
      //how can I get job parameters here
       return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
        .start(step1())
        .next(step2())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step1() {}

  @Bean
  public Step step2() {}

}
```

My application

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run my job like below:

```
java -jar sample.jar parameterkey=parameterValue
```

My question is how can I get job parameters in job1()? thanks

Comment: That's is not possible. In `job1`, you are defining the job (happens at configuration time). However, job parameters are passed in at runtime (which is too late to get them there). Why do you need them there? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to build steps  dynamically based on some input.

Comment: ok in that case job parameter is not appropriate for what you are trying to achieve. You can use a JVM system property for example.

Comment: Do you mean something like java -Dkey=value -jar sample.jar? How can I access it in job1() then? Can I have some example code?

Comment: yes, you can get it with `System.getProperty(key)`

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine how can I write java code to run job with passing the system property? like  java -Dkey=value -jar sample.jar